# custom delegate being null iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, delegates

I know this should be a simple thing to fix, but I can't see what's going wrong. May be extra pair will help. Here is what I am trying to do.

1. In my table view controller, there is an (+) button on the navigation controller to add new item.
2. I have a modal segue that takes it to the next view controller. User fills in a form and hit saves the table view controller reloads with the newly added record.

To do this, I implemented protocol with a delegate.

**MyFormViewController.h**

```
protocol MyCustomDelegate <NSObject>

@required

- (void)addNewRecord:(myFormViewController *)formViewController itemToAdd:(Item *)item;

@end

@property (nonatomic,weak) id<MyCustomDelegate> delegate;
```

**MyFormViewController.m**

```
@synthesize delegate;

- (IBAction)addItem:(id)sender {
    Item *item = [[Item alloc]init];

    item.name = itemName.text;
    item.desc = itemDescription.text;

    // I am having problem here, self.delegate is being null even though, it's being set in    prepareForSegue.
    if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(addNewRecord:)]) {

        [self.delegate addNewRecord:self itemToAdd:item];
    }
    else{

        // delegate is getting set to null for some reason.
        NSLog(@"Delegate method not getting called...%@",delegate);
    }
}
```

in **MyTableViewController.h**

@interface MyTableViewController : UITableViewController

**MyTableViewController.m**

```
-(void)addItem:(myFormViewController *)formViewController itemToAdd:(Item *)item{

    if(item)
    {
        MyClass *_itemClass = [[MyClass alloc]initWithPath:@"items/"];

        [_itemClass addItemForUser:item];
    }

    [formViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

in my **prepareForSegue**  method I am setting my tableviewcontroller as delegate.

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{

   if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"addItemSegue"]){

    myFormViewController *_showaddTopic = [[myFormViewController alloc]init];

    _showaddTopic.delegate = self;
}
```

After all this, my delegate in myFormViewController is being set to "null". I am not sure why it's not working. It's pretty basic stuff but giving me hard time.

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
myFormViewController *_showaddTopic = [[myFormViewController alloc]init];
_showaddTopic.delegate = self;
```

There's your problem. You are *creating* a *new* MyFormViewController. But that's the wrong MyFormViewController; you want to use the one that is *already* the segue's destination controller. So you are setting the wrong object's delegate.

(PS Notice my use of a capital letter to start the name of a class? Always do that.)

Comment: Thank you for the response. It worked, it solved the problem and gave me another one. My [self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(addNewRecord:)] is returning NO all the time. Do you see why ?

Comment: Yes, I do. Ask a separate question and give me the link to it.

Answer (score 0):

maybe _showaddTopic.delegate = self; can not written here and shuold this object alloc after at once